# Unable to Connect to Google Cloud MySQL using Google App Engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

1. I am trying to follow the steps from [Getting Started using Cloud MySQL and PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emS4n.png) however I am still getting the SQL error below.
2. Steps I have done so far,

   a. Created a database in Google Cloud MySQL

   b. Created a user and a password,

[My Connection Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emS4n.png)

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Are we following the same tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/blob/master/2-structured-data/config/settings.yml.dist

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your connection values are wrong

Comment: @Hackerman, Yes its the same tutorial. I followed the steps, and changed credentials to `settings.yml` Is there a way I can send you the file to see, if I am doing it wrong?

Comment: @Hackerman See my connection page from `settings.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to open up the firewall on your Cloud SQL instance to allow your IP address to access it. For testing purposes, you can open it for all IP addresses by:

1. Navigating to your Database Instance
2. Clicking 'Edit'
3. Click 'Authorize Networks'
4. Click 'Add Network'
5. Type 0.0.0.0/0 to open up your database to all networks.

NOTE: You should only use that setting for initial testing as it will open up your instance to connections from any IP address. Once you verify that's the issue, remove that entry and create an entry for just the IP addresses you'll be connecting from.

Comment: When I created an instance for the database, I got an IP Address,. Is that the IP I should add under the Authorize Networks?

Comment: I've updated my wording. I meant navigate to 'Cloud SQL' within the Google Cloud console, click the name of the database you want to edit, then click the 'Edit' icon. You will temporarily be opening it up its firewall to all IP addresses. When you are done testing, you will remove that entry, find the IP address of the host you'll be connecting from and add its IP address. That will cause your database to only allow that host to connect. The 0.0.0.0/0 should only be used for testing purposes.

Comment: see my connection settings let me know what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 0):

From **AppEngine Standard Environment** you do not need an IP to connect to a **First Generation Cloud MySQL** instance. For PDO you can use as DSN:

```
mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-mysql-instance-name>;dbname=<database-name>
```

Starting from **AppEngine Flexible Environment** or if you use a **Second Generation Cloud MySQL** you need to install *cloud_sql_proxy* - see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql and/or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/cloud-sql/

If what you really want is to test locally with the Cloud SQL from Google Cloud you will also need the same *cloud_sql_proxy*.

Comment: I am using **Second Generation Cloud** and I have installed **Cloud SQL Proxy** what steps am I missing?

Comment: See my Connection Settings let me know what's causing the error.